# Platform doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy Central/Client role

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

In settings I see Bluetooth is turned on. But

`- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central`

returns

`central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported`

What does it mean?

iPad model mc796rs/a and iOS 7.0.3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iPad 2 does not have a bluetooth 4 (low energy) chip, so [`CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) means that it is not supported.